# conanException while building boost 1.79.0

Tags: boost, conan, bjam

I am trying to build `boost-1.79.0` using conan package manager in windows-10 home.

My visual studio version is vs2022. I am facing error :

```
  self.run('.\\b2 --toolset=msvc %s install' %(' '.join(b2_args)))
        ConanException: Error 1 while executing .\b2 --toolset=msvc -- 
        prefix=C:\.conan\1f4418\1 runtime-link=shared link=shared 
        variant=release -d2 address-model=64 install
```

I have run `.\bootstrap` and set environment variable correctly.

Comment: It would be necessary way more information: Conan version, the recipe (is it from ConanCenter?) the command to reproduce, the full output of the command. This looks like more like a support request, more than a Q&A, I'd suggest filing a ticket with all that information in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues